# Is there a way to set a max limit to math operations in dart?

Tags: dart

I have the following math operation:

```
    var _baseFontSize = _userfontsize*8;
    if (_baseFontSize > 14) { _baseFontSize = 14.0; }
```

Essentially whatever the `_userfontsize` is, my `_baseFontSize` should be 8x that number, but never exceeding 14.0.

Instead of doing this math operation in 2 lines as might be conventional, is there a way to set a max limit to this (or any given) math operation in dart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can import `dart:math` and do something like this with [`min`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.15.1/dart-math/min.html):

```
var _baseFontSize = min(_userfontsize * 8, 14.0);
```

> `T min<T extends num>(T a, T b)`
>
> Returns the lesser of two numbers.